# neural networks for missing features

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have a dataset wit A...F features for training. Now my prediction data set to predict the key feature does not have observations of 3 feature used in the training set. So I have only a subset of features for prediction whereas the neural newtork is trained for a broader range of features.

How can I handle such problem? Can you use a neural network for the missing features? In my mind came the following: First, I use a neural network on training set, but now to train on the missing features. So I can predict the 3 missing features from the prediction data set. Now, I use a neural network on this new prediction data set.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running the neural-network on your dataset even though features are missing? A neural-network does not need all features to be present.

You can simply set all missing features values to `0` for the neural network, as neural networks don't see a difference between `0` and `feature is missing`. Why not you ask? If you set an input value to 0, that means all the connections from that input node will have a `0` value a well: adding nothing to the hidden neurons that are connected to that input node.

But before you do that, try any of these:

[image]
[source](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-handle-missing-features-in-machine-learning)

As 1 seems the case for you!